# Empty parent DIV but not child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs included one in the other:

```
<DIV id="DIV_1">
    parent_contents
    parent_contents

     <DIV id="DIV_2">
         child_contents
         child_contents
     </DIV>
</DIV>
```

I want to remove parent_contents, but not the child_contents. When I do:

```
$('#DIV_1').remove();
```

I lose the child contents...

Comment: Not only that, but you lose them too.

Comment: @Diodeus, rather than deriding, it would be better if you edit the question and correct it.

Comment: So you want DIV_2 to be still child of DIV_1 or you want to remove DIV_1 and keep DIV_2?

Comment: Yes I want that DIV_2 to be still child of DIV_1

Comment: I've performed thousands of edits already.

Comment: do you want to keep content of DIV_1 but remove DIV_1 and keep DIV_2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out the textnodes and remove them :

```
$('#DIV_1').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ykah/2/)

or to leave just `#DIV_2`, filter out just that one element:

```
$('#DIV_1').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.id != 'DIV_2';
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ykah/1/)

Comment: I used the solution 2, even if I would prefer to keep DIV_1 info... But I reload the content so it's fine for me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure one of the easiest ways would be to copy the DIV_2 child content into a variable, then simply append it to DIV_1 after emptying it.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/RNakX/1)

```
var $temp = $('#DIV_2');
$("#DIV_1").empty().append($temp);
```

Comment: Note that this would remove any data related to the elements, event handlers etc. -> http://jsfiddle.net/RNakX/2/

Comment: Very true, didn't realize that! Touche @adeneo :)